# What is the bash equivalent of `modpath` in csh?

Tags: shell, hp-ux

This is the error that I got.

```
modpath: Command not found.
```

I'm suspecting that it's because `modpath` is a csh command but not the right syntax for bash. So, I want to know what's its equivalent in bash. Thanks!

> modpath - change global search path for dynamically loadable kernel modules
>
> modpath allows users with appropriate privilege to modify the global search path used to locate object files for dynamically loadable kernel modules. The search path modifications take effect immediately and affect all subsequent loads for all users on the system.
>
> pathname may be either a colon-separated list of absolute pathnames or NULL. If the former, these path names represent directories which should be searched for all autoloads of loadable kernel modules and for demand loads (see modload(2)) where the module is given by a simple file name.    This list of directories will be prepended to the existing list of directories and so will be searched before any directories given in previous calls to modpath and before the default location which is always searched last.  The directories do not have to exist on the system at the time modpath is called, or when a load actually takes place. If pathname is equal to NULL, the global search path is set back to its initial default value, /stand/dlkm/mod.d.
>
> Notes: modpath is currently implemented as a macro.

[source: http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=2&page=modpath&manpath=HP-UX-11.11]

Comment: If you can tell  what `modpath` does in a `csh` shell, perhaps  we can help you find a `bash` equivalent of it here

Comment: `modpath` - change global search path for dynamically loadable kernel modules

[source: http://modman.unixdev.net/?sektion=2&page=modpath&manpath=HP-UX-11.11]

Comment: I think it is something that modifies a path. Because what I actually want to do is `modpath -d <some path>`, which is the csh equivalent of it. The -d will delete the path component.

Comment: Apparently `modpath`has nothing to do with`$PATH`, and is not specific to bash or can.

Comment: The page you link to describes a C library function, not a shell command.

Comment: `modpath` is not part of `csh` its a C API (the clue is that it is in section 2 of the man pages).  What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: For some reason, I opened another terminal and I do the same modpath command, it works now. Not sure what happened, maybe some environmental issues. How do I mark this question as solved?

Comment: Just post how you fixed it as an answer then accept it.  Trouble is, you don't know how you fixed it.

Comment: I want to do `modpath -d <some path>`. I actually wanted to know more about `modpath` but I can't find anything accurate. Like others said, I somehow land on some C library function page or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation now included in the question, `modpath` has nothing to do with `$PATH`, and it's not specific to csh, bash, or any other shell.

On my system (Ubuntu 16.10), there is no command, system call, or library function by that name, and there appears to be no installable package that provides it. The documentation you quoted is for HP-UX, which is a different flavor of UNIX. I suspect it's a system call that exists only on HP-UX.

Since you've been able to invoke `modpath` from csh, there's probably a command that's some kind of wrapper around the system call, though the documentation is for the system call itself, not for the command.

If such a command exists, you should be able to find it by typing

```
which modpath
```

from csh. If that gives you the full path to the command, then from bash you can either use that full path to invoke the command, or you can add the appropriate directory to your `$PATH`.  (You very likely have a different setting for `$PATH` in csh vs. bash.)

Comment: Thanks. It helps me to identify what happened in that terminal that don't accept it.